# SQL - Percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a query, which results in a percentage.

The query I have at the moment looks like this:

```
select COUNT(CREATE_WEEKDAY),
       CREATE_WEEKDAY,
       COUNT(CREATE_WEEKDAY) * 100 /
from call_view
WHERE (create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
AND (create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
AND CUSTOMER_COMPANY_NAME = "Company"
group by CREATE_WEEKDAY
```

If I start the query the result shows:

```
COUNT(CREATE_WEEKDAY) |  CREATE_WEEKDAY  |      COUNT(CREATE_WEEKDAY) * 100
111                        Friday              11100
225                        MONDAY              22500
```

and so on....

I want the last column to display the

```
"COUNT(CREATE_WEEKDAY) * 100 / SUM(COUNT(CREATE_WEEKDAY))"
```

->> this last part should be the `SUM` OF all the `CREATE_WEEKDAY`. In the example give  `= 111 + 225 = 336`

But this Code isn't working. I appreciate any help.

Cheers

Comment: Did you copy the query correctly? There's nothing after `/`, so it should report a syntax error.

Comment: @Barmar The OP want to know how put the `SUM(COUNT(*))` after `/`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza But he said he ran the query and got the stated results. He can't run that query.

Comment: @Barmar I know isnt the best write question, but you see header on that part is without `/` and final request say  `last part should be ...`

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I used the query from MotoGP and it's working fine =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `Sub-query`

First identify the total count for the given filter's(where clause)

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   call_view 
WHERE  ( create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
       AND ( create_year = Year(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
       AND customer_company_name = 'Company'
```

Then use this query in denominator to find percentage

```
SELECT Count(create_weekday), 
       create_weekday, 
       Count(create_weekday) * 100 / (SELECT Count(*) 
                                      FROM   call_view 
                                      WHERE 
       ( create_month = Month(Now() - 
                        INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
       AND ( create_year = Year( 
             Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
       AND customer_company_name = 
           'Company') 
FROM   call_view 
WHERE  ( create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
       AND ( create_year = Year(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
       AND customer_company_name = "Company" 
GROUP  BY create_weekday
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This query is exactly displaying , what I want to see :D

Answer (score 0):

Join with a subquery that calculates the total count.

```
select COUNT(*),
       CREATE_WEEKDAY,
       COUNT(*) * 100 / total_count
from call_view
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_count
            FROM call_view
            WHERE create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
            AND create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
            AND customer_company_name = "Company") AS x
WHERE (create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
AND (create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
AND CUSTOMER_COMPANY_NAME = "Company"
group by CREATE_WEEKDAY
```